# Codename One. Very slow work after build

Tags: codenameone

I'm developing my project in Codename One. UI creating from code, not GUI Designer. Application consists of three forms, as navigation I use Hamburger sidebar. The emulator works fine, but the builded application works very slow. Application was tested on Android. The degree of brake application depends on the number of components in the form. The situation has changed a little after we changed **android.asyncPaint** to *false*, but the operating speed remains slow.

Above all, Hamburger sidebar animation works strange. At first shows previous form, and then only shows the selected form. But this problem is not as important as the terrible brake application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 9 our of 10 cases this is caused by developers using gradients which are notoriously slow. It can also be triggered by tiling very small images or too many layers of transparency.

We have a performance monitor tool in the simulator that exposes some of these issues. You should also watch this video which covers most performance issues: http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---improve-application-performance-or-track-down-performance-issues.html

Comment: Yep. I'm use a lot of gradients to fill background on the components. It's would be convenient if i could do it without gradient or one-color images. But such an item in the settings does not :)

Comment: However, the change gradient to image with desired color speed up my app. Thanks for the answer!